# List of tuples to 2D array

Tags: haskell

I would like to create a matrix from a given list of tuples.
A tuple has `(row, column, value)` and I want to create `matrix[row][column] = value` with:

```
buildMatrix :: Int-> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
```

For example, given:

```
n = 3 (size of matrix)
list = [(1,2,1), (1,3,-1), (2,3,1)],
```

I would like to get

```
matrix = [[0,1,-1], [0,0,1], [0,0,0]]
```

What I tried so far:

```
buildMatrix n (i, j, v) = [ [ entry row column | column <- [1..n] ] | row <- [1..n] ]
    where
    entry x y
       | x == i && y == j = v
       | otherwise = 0
```

I am stuck at applying the function for each tuple, I was thinking about using map.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [out formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to format your future posts.

Comment: You want a fold (i.e. use "foldr") rather than a map. You want an initial array (e.g. one containing all zeros) and then you have to write a function which takes an array and an entry triple and returns the updated array. Take a look at the type of foldr and see how these plug in to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to change entry to check whether *any* tuple `(x,y,v)` exists in a given list:

```
buildMatrix :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
buildMatrix n xs = [ [ entry row column | column <- [1..n] ] | row <- [1..n] ]
  where
    entry x y = maybe 0 id (findValue x y xs)
    findValue x y [] = Nothing
    findValue x y ((i,j,v):xs')
       | x == i && y == j = Just v
       | otherwise        = findValue x y xs'
```

However that's a little bit of a hassle. There is already `lookup :: Eq a => a -> [(a,b)] -> Maybe b`, and our `findValue` looks almost the same. So let's use that one instead:

```
buildMatrix :: Int -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> [[Int]]
buildMatrix n xs = [ [ entry row column | column <- [1..n] ] | row <- [1..n] ]
  where
    entry x y = maybe 0 id (lookup (x,y) (indexed xs))
    indexed   = map (\(x,y,v) -> ((x,y),v))
```

That's one way to achive your goal. Unfortunately, this algorithm has a worst-case time-complexity of (n²k), where `n` is your matrix size and `k` is the number of elements in `xs`. One can choose another algorithm to improve it to (n²+k log k)=(n²), but that's left as an exercise.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to get (n²) if the input list can contain duplicates. I also don't understand where you get an `n log n` term. I'd expect something `Map`-like to get you 2n² log n extra, and I'd expect an array to get you n² extra. Am I missing something?

Comment: @dfeuer Should be k log k +n^2. Sort the tuples (k log k), traverse them as you build the matrix(n^2 since no lookup cost). Duplicates can be handled during the initial sort.

Comment: @Zeta, I think I fixed it. My numbers came from the assumption that `k = n^2`. If there are many duplicates, then sorting is wasteful, and it would be better to use a map to dispose of duplicates along the way. As I mentioned, though, an array seems more appropriate. `accumArray` should do the trick.